# Does there exist a cross-browser JavaScript library for simulating keyboard manipulation of an element?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, ui-automation

I'm well aware of the standard event firing mechanisms for browsers, but I have a need for a JavaScript library that will simulate cursor and insertion point navigation via the keyboard. In particular, I need a library that will allow me to move the insertion point, but will also handle expanding or collapsing a selection range of text if, say, the virtual shift key is "pressed" while navigating with a virtual arrow key. Does such a cross-browser JavaScript library exist?

This is intended for use in a browser automation library, so suggestions of things like Selenium would be inappropriate. Furthermore, I would like to avoid libraries that have dependencies on large JavaScript frameworks like jQuery, if possible. Finally, this needs to be injectable within a page, so non-JavaScript solutions won't work for my requirements.

Assuming I have an HTML page that looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>keyboard</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="editor" value="hello world" />
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to call, in JavaScript, something like this:

```
function moveCursor() {
  var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
  editor.focus();

  // Hypothetical API here. This would need to be
  // adjusted to be used with the actual library.
  // Assume the pressKey() is defined as:
  //
  //   pressKey(element, keyCode, isShiftPressed)
  //
  keyboardSimulator.pressKey(editor, keys.END);
  keyboardSimulator.pressKey(editor, keys.LEFT, true);
  keyboardSimulator.pressKey(editor, keys.LEFT, true); 
}
```

After calling this JavaScript function, I would expect the focus in my page to be on the editor element, and for "ld" in the "hello world" value to be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there *are* libraries that do these things.

One of them is called Syn, and is included in bitovi FuncUnit:

http://funcunit.com

https://github.com/bitovi/syn

Answer (score 0):

No such library exists. This would be an enormous security hole if this were actually allowed. The only thing you can do is to trap keystrokes and act upon them, eg create special hotkeys that when trapped trigger some special functionality you have created in javascript.

(BTW: Some extensions such as Lastpass and Lazarus that appear to send keystrokes to a control, actually just set the text property.)

Comment: And yet, by very clever manipulation of selection ranges and setting the text property, it *is* possible to simulate this behavior. I presume this wouldn't pose a security risk. I'm hoping someone has already done the legwork to handle the edge cases to make such a simulation robust.

Comment: Hmmm, that's an interesting angle. If you come across something or work up a solution yourself please let me know. (Always on the lookout for a new automation technique :)

Comment: Yeah, I definitely will. According to this page on YUI, [link](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/simulate.html#simulating-key-events) , FireFox will happily insert key events.

I'm pretty sure Bitovi Syn is probably the best pragmatic solution at the moment, however it's proving difficult to integrate into my Ember js app for me.